# Javascript: What is eslintcache file and why is always generated in create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, eslint

**What is `eslintcache`**

Why it is always auto generating on the react app.

[eslintcache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7HU0.png)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) goes over your code and reports stylistic errors. Usually going over the whole code is unneccessary, because you only changed a few files since the last run. To be able to track which files changed, and which errors occured in the files which were not changed, eslint is writing a cache (into the file you found).

Usually that file is supposed to be in `/node_modules/.cache/`, so you usually won't notice it. That it resides in your working directory is [a bug](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10161).

Comment: Not a bug: `The cache is stored in .eslintcache by default.`